adaptations reset after nox sensor replacement bmw e91
I need to replace my nox sensor. I know the procedure for changing the part, but i don't know how to reset the relevant subsystem of the ECU so that it understand it has been changed. I have an xlite creader elite code reader.
I wonder if just removing the battery and waiting 15 min should be enough. Please help.

According to this forum post, in order to reset ONLY the NOX sensor, you have to use something like ISTA+ software to do it. (Note: No affiliation to software or link.) In the forum post, ISTA+ software is the only way they know how to just reset that. I'm not sure pulling the fuse or battery for any length of time would do you any good. It may be the memory for this portion is set until software reset. Also, with BMW's, you have to worry about the car freaking out with the battery disconnected, because it will think it's a different battery and you'll end up needing the car reprogrammed to accept the same battery. BMWs can be finicky cars.
